# Advanced PHP foreach() loop..(nested if/else)

Tags: php, loops, foreach, break

I'm having a bit of a brain-fart here...lol

I was using a forloop() initially for this.. but then the conditions got a bit more advanced on things I needed to check for, as well as the output based on found/not found..

My problem is ensuring that on consecutive loops.. the 'else' on the (no access) potion only gets echo'd once...  but of course on every 'loop' it will check from the top and if not a match output the 'no-access' text.. (on every iteration).. where it should only output once.

Originally there was only a few  if() statement/checks in the foreach() loop.. where a simple break; took care of things fine...

but these if()'s turned into if/else.. which means the else will get 'triggered' on the next 'loop'..  how can this be prevented?

```
$arrwebinars = ("Name1", "Name3");

foreach($arrwebinars as $webinar) {

   /* Webinar 1 */
   if($webinar == 'Name1') {    
        if($web01_title != '') {
            echo "available";                   
        } else {
            echo "not available";
        }
  } else {
    echo "no access";
  } 

  /* Webinar 2 */
  if ($webinar == 'Name2') {    
     if ($web02_title != '') {
        echo "available";                   
     } else {
        echo "not available";
     }
  } else {
     echo "no access";
  }

  /* Webinar 3 */
  if ($webinar == 'Name3') {    
    if($web03_title != '') {
        echo "available";                   
    } else {
        echo "not available";
    }
  } else {
    echo "no access";
  }
}
```

is there some other sort of 'control' I can use to ensure the main if/else only gets executed once?

Sorry , I am having a hard time trying to describe this one, hopefully the code explains it all (and the problem)

thanks.

---

update:
Current State:  reverted back to foreach() loop.

User is only authorized for 2 vids (#5 & #6 we'll say..can be any of the 6 in reality)

Upon first loop/iteration.. vids 1-4 output (no access for you!) (because they dont, only #5 & #6 as stated above)

no. 5 outputs the embed code fine (access)

no. 6 says 'No access for you'.. (even though they do/should have access)

Upon the scond iteration..vids 1-4 are duplicated, and again say "No access for you" (outside of it being a duplication..this is correct).. however, vid #5 NOW says "no access for you" (first loop it outputted fine, second loop it is looking for a new 'match' while not what I want.. in theory this is correct.. but should have a duplicate)

Vid #6 is NOW outputting the embed code (where as on first loop it did not)..

The user has only purchased access to 2 vids.. so the loop only happens twice.

but I get '12' echo's

No matter what I should only get 6 echo's  with 1 out put per video  (available/not available -or- no access)

I cant seem to wrap my head around this today.. :(

Goal I want achieve:

6 outputs TOTAL

each output (echo) should ONLY have:
available or not available printed (this is the nested conditional check for the blank title)
-or-
no access

there are 6 video to check against.
the user can have purchased access to 1 or up to all 6 vids

first check is: is the webinar name in their purchased array found in the total available 6 vids available

second tier conditional check:
if YES (match found == access)...then check to see if the title is missing (if there output access [video embed code]... if not there output text 'not available yet')

(going back to first conditional check) if there is NO ACCESS (match not found).. output 'no access' text.

This works if I wanted duplicates on the stage/page.. (but I dont!)  LOL..

I need to be limited to ONLY 6 outputs,.. as there are only a total of 6 vids available.

I DO NOT WANT:

on loop 1 it outputs access for vid#1 and #2-#6 are no access..
on loop 2 it re-states all of these outputs, has vid#1 no-access now, vid#2 has access and vids #3-#6 are no access...

etc.etc..  and the cycle continues.    I'm getting lost on this one!..

thanks!

Comment: Isn't `$arrwebinars = ("Name1", "Name3");` supposed to be `$arrwebinars = array("Name1", "Name3");`

Comment: Try to format your code properly. What is the "main if/else"?

Comment: @KevBot - yes.. was typo as I threw it after the fact to give some context.

 msfoster - the main if/else is the if($webinar) portion..

Each main if/else has a nested if/else.

Main checks for 'access' to the $webinar.. if access, then I check for availability (nested if/else)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but your code could be shortened greatly.

```
$webinars = array('one', 'two', 'Name3');
$web0_title = 'not empty'; // Just a demo

for ( $i = 0; $i < count($webinars); $i++ )
{

    $access = FALSE;
    $available = FALSE;
    $name = 'Name' . $i;
    $title = 'web' . $i . '_title';

    if ( $webinars[$i] == $name ) {

        if ( ! empty( $$title ) ) {

            $available = TRUE;

        }

        $access = TRUE;

    }

    // Simple debug, not sure what you want to accomplish
    echo 'Webinar: ' . $webinars[$i] . ' <br />';
    echo 'Availability: ' . ( $available ? 'Available' : 'Not Available' ) . '<br />';
    echo 'Access: ' . ( $access ? 'Access' : 'No Access'  ) . '<br /><br />';

}
```

Edit: Just read your comments so I updated it.

Comment: hmm  this is close.  I tried ti implement it.. but I ran into the problem of: I only need to check for title IF they have access (if webinar == name) its a 2-tiered conditional.

I shouldnt be outputting anything 'Availability' related is Access is false.

Comment: just posting for myself now I guess..lol

Seems I need to go back to a foreach() loop?  since there is no telling how many 'authorized' videos will be in the users $webinars() array  (this is populated when the user logs in and queries the DB for all purchased access).. but I need to check against (currently) 6 available ones.

either the count is getting messed up or I get duplicated output on the iterations.  :(

Comment: summary added to first post!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to stop considering that "row" when you encounter a "no access" then you could simply `continue;` after each no-access.  or do you wish to check the others even if you encounter "no access" on the first, just to fail silently in that case?

Comment: Yes this is more on track with what I am trying to do. (I believe)

I want to check the first block (if/else)
and either output 'available' (which will be some embed code for a video).. or not available (meaning they do have access, match was found in array, but video is not ready message)...

If a match was not found.. then output the no access (you did not purchase message,...with some other text).

WHat I see right now is:

Comment: continued...

on first loops  first match/video is found.. and it outputs embed code.
Consecutive blocks all output no-access (simple break would stop this I believe?) 

On second loop.. the first video above is now listed as no-access and the second video is found/echo'd.. and the rest (of course) are no-access.

So using the above (only 3) example, I get 9 total echo's.. all different depending on the loop iteration

Comment: @Eliel -

It looks as if you are just checking the boolean of access and availability. But we output availability text based on the value of access not the value of availability. 

The 'value' of availability gets set based on the boolean....but to show it or not is based on the value of access.  The more work into your example.. the more I see it much like the first attempt/example given?

Comment: finally a simple solution.. after all this time I was simply OVER thinking it.   Using in_array() instead of a loop solved the duplication problem!  (DUH! cant believe I wasnt thinking of that.. stupid head cold/alergies today!)  I'll update answer when I get it cleaned up.  Thanks everyone for the colab..  helped me focus a bit more.